# Can a List be somehow assigned to a list of another class after being instantiated?

Tags: java, list, listview, javafx, collections

I'm trying to deal with `ListView` in JavaFX.

```
    @FXML
    ListView<? extending Animals> listView;
```

I want to continuously assign `listView` items to `ObservableLists` of classes that extend `Animals`.

```
    listView.setItems(new ObservableList<Dogs>);
    listView.setItems(new ObservableList<Cats>); //error
    listView.setItems(new ObservableList<Horses>); //error
```

Of course, I know that I can't do that this way and why, but since ObservableLists handle refreshing `ListView`, I'd really like to use `ObservableLists<Dogs>`, `ObservableList<Cats>`, `ObservableList<Horses>` instead of using `ObservableList<Animals>` and converting my `Dogs`, `Cats`, and `Horses` list to `Animals` list. Also I need `Dogs`'s properties in my `Dogs` list, so storing `Dogs` in an `Animals` list is not an option.

I'd like to know if there's anyway to do this, and if there's not, what's the most efficient way to bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
@FXML
private ListView<Animal> listView ;
```

and then

```
ObservableList<Dog> dogs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(...);
listView.getItems().setAll(dogs);
```

or

```
ObservableList<Cat> cats = FXCollections.observableArrayList(...);
listView.getItems().setAll(cats);
```

This may or may not work with however it is you retrieve items from the `ListView` (if you need to do that at all). You can also consider creating multiple `ListView`s (`ListView<Dog>`, `ListView<Cat>`, etc) and switching them in and out of the UI as you need.

Comment: It should be noted that `listView.getItems().setAll(someList);` simply ***copies*** the content of `someList` to the `items` list currently used in `listView`. In contrast to `listView.setItems(someList);` changes in `someList` do not update the `ListView`...